# How to use java script for dynamically created button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

c#

```
 foreach (DataRow Row in oDs.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        LitPreferances.Text += "<Li ID=LI_" + Row["pk_Preference_Branch_ID"].ToString() +"_"+ Row["pk_Preference_BranchType_ID"].ToString() +">" + Row["Branch_Name"].ToString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' title='delete' class='itemDelete' onclick='return RemoveBranch();' tooltip='Remove Branch'>Remove</a></Li>";
                    }
```

I am having some branch name which are placed in oDs Dataset and i am also creating a remove button in front of particular branch. That remove button have a javascript which is not working as expected.

Javascript

```
  function RemoveBranch() {
        $('.itemDelete').live('click',
    function () {
        $(this).closest('Li').remove();
    }
);
        return false;
        }
```

Its showing error as object doesn't support property or method 'live'

Comment: use `on` instead of `live`

Answer (score 0):

**live** is depriciated use **[.on](http://jqapi.com/#p=on)** :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
          .
          .
          .
    </head>
</html>

function RemoveBranch() {
        $('body').on('click','.itemDelete',function () {
        $(this).closest('Li').remove();
    });
 return false;
}
```

Comment: I am still on same plateform , JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

Comment: Are you using jQuery ??

Comment: If i will jquery than type is remain same na i.e. <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

Comment: means i just want to know that what will make difference if i will go with jquery ?

Comment: include this : <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: I am using jquery 1.2 and i can not change for higher version as application is old . Can you please tell me if there is any other option up to 1.2

Answer (score 0):

```
I got one solution over there, just simply used

 function RemoveBranch() { $("#ULPreferences li").click(function () { 
$(this).remove(); }); }
```